# Do i have to release no-arc object in arc?

Tags: smtp, automatic-ref-counting

I am using library that is written in non arc (SMTP library - by using compiler flag to keep it non arc). Now, one of my classes is registered as delegate to this library, and library is passing me object of retain count 1. Pre-arc i should have released such object, but now in arc i don't know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that pre ARC you would have to release every instance variable of every class before the object if the class is released itself. The rules pre ARC say,

- When you create an object using new, alloc, or copy, the object has a
  retain count of 1. You are responsible for sending the object a release or
  autorelease message when you’re finished with it. That way, it gets cleaned
  up when its useful life is over.
- When you get hold of an object via any other mechanism, assume it has
  a retain count of 1 and that it has already been autoreleased. You don’t
  need to do any further work to make sure it gets cleaned up. If you’re going
  to hang on to the object for any length of time, retain it and make sure to
  release it when you’re finished.
- If you retain an object, you need to (eventually) release or autorelease it.
  Balance these retains and releases.

So, if your going to use the object temporarily (like in a single function's scope) you do nothing, but for longer use you can retain it (increasing retain count to 2) and release it when your done, the initial retain count of 1 will be the library's work to do.